# transient jupyter notebook failures with "database is locked"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

[image]

Recently my jupyter notebooks have been encountering a `Unexpected error while saving file: ... database is locked`

I've been running these things for years and only in the last two weeks has this problem started occuring.  Nothing has changed in my anaconda python environment. The notebooks are stored on a network drive on my windows pc.  I launch `jupyter notebook` at the command line from inside that network drive.  Nothing I can do otherwise than kill the jupyter notebook process and reload everything.  A collegue is facing similar situation.

Very scant information on this.  The closest thing I've found is a reference here https://groups.google.com/g/jupyter/c/47GzvUm0jZA/m/o3jJagzEAgAJ

> The 'database is locked' error probably comes from an SQLite database
> we use to store notebook signatures as part of the trust mechanism.
> This usually arises because the database file is on an NFS filesystem.
> The default location on Linux is
> ~/.local/share/jupyter/nbsignatures.db .
> You can put the file
> somewhere else by configuring NotebookNotary.db_file . You can also
> set it to the special value ':memory:' to store the database in memory
> but if you do this, restarting the notebook server will lose the signatures, so all notebooks will be untrusted, meaning HTML output
> won't show up until you re-run them.

I haven't been able to find this NotebookNotary file on my windows to figure out what the configuration says.  I also don't have any good debugging ideas here.

=============

I found my jupyter config file. It doesn't say an explicit path to where the file is stored.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NotebookNotary(LoggingConfigurable) configuration
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## A class for computing and verifying notebook signatures.

## The hashing algorithm used to sign notebooks.
#c.NotebookNotary.algorithm = 'sha256'

## The sqlite file in which to store notebook signatures. By default, this will
#  be in your Jupyter data directory. You can set it to ':memory:' to disable
#  sqlite writing to the filesystem.
#c.NotebookNotary.db_file = ''

## The secret key with which notebooks are signed.
#c.NotebookNotary.secret = b''

## The file where the secret key is stored.
#c.NotebookNotary.secret_file = ''

## A callable returning the storage backend for notebook signatures. The default
#  uses an SQLite database.
#c.NotebookNotary.store_factory = traitlets.Undefined
```